# Carregar lista de um tipo em uma View de outro tipo

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net-mvc, razor

Estou realizando um cadastro de profissional e claro, minha View esta tipada com este Model. Porém no cadastro preciso inserir Especialização e Tipo (outros 2 models diferentes). Estes 2 últimos models precisam vir como listas e aparecer em checkboxes dentro de um Select (HTML).

Até agora tenho o seguinte:

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ProfessionalSpecializationDAO pSpecializationDAO = new ProfessionalSpecializationDAO();
            ViewBag.ListProfessionalSpecialization = pSpecializationDAO.ListProfessionalSpecialization(0);

            ProfessionalTypeDAO pTypeDAO = new ProfessionalTypeDAO();
            ViewBag.ListProfessionalType = pTypeDAO.ListProfessionalType(0);

            return View();
        }
```

View (HTML):

```
<div class="editor-field">
                    @{
                        ViewBag.ProfessionalSpecialization as List<ProfessionalSecialization>;

                        foreach (var item in ViewBag.ProfessionalSpecialization)
                        {                            
                            Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.Title);
                        }
                        Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdProfessionalSpecialization);
                    }
                </div>
```

Provavelmente deve ser por que esta faltando referência ao Model `ProfessionalSpecialization`. Não sei como referenciá-los.

Comment: Respondi como fazer a referência, mas qual o erro que está dando mesmo!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dentro de um `select` não é possível, mas você pode emular isso usando uma `div` e setando o `style` com o valor `overflow-y:auto;height:200px;` que faz com que a div pareça com um `select` aberto.
Sendo assim, acredito que algumas mudanças no seu código pode resolver o problema.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ProfessionalSpecializationDAO psDao = new ProfessionalSpecializationDAO();

    return View(psDao.ListProfessionalSpecialization(0));
}
```

E a view fica assim, no início:

```
@model List<ManyLife.ASP.Areas.Professional.Models.ProfessionalSpecialization>
```

E logo depois você complementa:

```
<div class="editor-field" style="overflow-y:auto;height:200px;">
@{
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {                            
        Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.Title);
    }
}
</div>
```

Caso você queira usar outro `model` por algum motivo especial, você pode usar `ViewBag` para passar os dados para a View e fazer um parse direto na View, assim:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ProfessionalUser professional = new ProfessionalUser();
    professional.IdProfessionalSpecialization = 13;
    professional.Name = "Teacher";

    ProfessionalSpecializationDAO psDao = new ProfessionalSpecializationDAO();
    ViewBag.ListProfessionalSpecialization = psDao.ListProfessionalSpecialization(0);

    ProfessionalTypeDAO pTypeDAO = new ProfessionalTypeDAO();
    ViewBag.ListProfessionalType = pTypeDAO.ListProfessionalType(0);

    return View(professional);
}
```

E a View fica assim:

```
@using ManyLife.ASP.Areas.Professional.Models
@model ManyLife.ASP.Areas.Professional.Models.ProfessionalUser
```

...

```
<div class="editor-field" style="overflow-y:auto;height:200px;">
<label>Especialização</label>
@{
    foreach (var item in (List<ProfessionalSpecialization>)ViewBag.ListProfessionalSpecialization)
    {                            
        Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.Title);
    }
    Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdProfessionalSpecialization);
}
</div>
```

...

```
<div class="editor-field" style="overflow-y:auto;height:200px;">
<label>Tipo de profissional</label>
@{
    foreach (var item in (List<ProfessionalType>)ViewBag.ListProfessionalType)
    {                            
        Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.Title);
    }
    Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdProfessionalSpecialization);
}
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Boa tarde.

Para referenciar basta usar o seguinte:

```
@using Aplicacao.Model.Class
```

Você pode referenciar em cima da referencia padrão do model que você recebe os dados da Action:

```
@using Aplicacao.Model.Class
@model IEnumerable<Aplicacao.Model.Class>
```

Comment: @using ManyLife.ASP.Areas.Professional.Models.ProfessionalSpecialization

não funciona também.